# Preloading a Java library in DB2, similar to ORACLE's loadjava

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, db2, java

*Edit to add details to clarify, based on Chris' comment*:

A Java stored procedure depends on external libraries. Locally it compiles successfully, since they are [added to the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10388171/341929). But when deploying on the server it fails, since it cannot resolve these dependencies at runtime.

---

Does DB2 have any functionality to automatically preload a library / Java stored procedure?
I'm looking for something similar to [ORACLE's `loadjava`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96659/02_load.htm):

```
loadjava -u myuser/MYPW -resolve mail-1.4.3.jar
loadjava -u myuser/MYPW -resolve aws-java-sdk-1.3.8.jar
```

Comment: I think by preload you really mean compile Java code as a stored procedure inside the database? Because when I look at the link you supplied that appears to be what is going on. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Confirmed: the Java stored procedure depends on those two libraries. Locally they are in the classpath, so it compiles successfully. But when deploying on the server it fails, since it cannot resolve these dependencies at runtime.

Comment: Just curious if what was suggested below was helpful and if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what I believe you are after is creating Java routines (ie, stored procedures implemented in Java and stored within DB2).

You will want to follow the documentation in this section on [Java routines](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0009196.html). Pay special attention to the [Creating](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/t0020639.html), [Building](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/t0020617.html), and [Deploying](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0006348.html) sections.

And even though this is an older article, you may wish to check out this article ["Solve common problems with DB2 UDB Java stored procedures"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510law/index.html) on developerworks. It also discusses the when/where of using Java routines in DB2, how you go about creating them, and common problems encountered.