# Does DB2 have equivalents for Oracle's UTL_ENCODE and UTL_RAW modules?

Tags: oracle, db2

I'm looking for something similar to:

```
utl_smtp.command(conn, utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(<username>)));
```

I couldn't find any reference among the [DB2's system-defined modules](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055176.html) and I've read that:

> after migrating to DB2 there is a little surprise - there is nothing like `UTL_RAW` and `UTL_ENCODE` functions

that was [written on March 28, 2010](http://hoteljavaopensource.blogspot.ca/2010/03/oracle-db2-migration.html).

Considering that DB2's Oracle compatibility has increased with every release from v9, do the newer versions of DB2 provide any equivalents for Oracle's `UTL_ENCODE` and `UTL_RAW`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are correct. It does not look like DB2 has built in support for base64 encoding.

So that would leave the following as options:

1. Handle the encoding within your programs.
2. Write a [Java routine (stored procedure)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17646/preloading-a-java-library-in-db2-similar-to-oracles-loadjava) to handle it.
3. Using a different [encryption scheme](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005815.html). DB2 comes with encryption built into itself. There is an [ENCRYPT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004211.html) function. Check it out.

Be careful with Java implementations of base64 though. A coworker of mine has mentioned he has seen a bug in all versions of it, in which "words" that have duplicate letters can decrypt into junk. So be careful and double check your base64 encoding/decoding.